# Mysterious drive letter on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, mount

Recently I've noted a "Q:" drive letter on my computer which I can't access, giving "Access denied".

`MOUNTVOL` gives the following.

```
\\?\Volume{830815a7-9c08-11e3-afef-b0ee45f5b28c}\
    Q:\
```

I can unmount it using `MOUNTVOL /D`, but it comes back on reboot.

This volume has an entry under *MountedDevices* registry key, but I cannot determine where it comes from.

The drive letter does not appear inside `diskmgmt.msc`, either.

How can I determine where this Volume is coming from?

Comment: Do you have some Microsoft Office version installed?

Comment: @and31415 I've got Office 2003, Office 2010 Starter and Office 365 installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drive Q comes from [Microsoft Application Virtualization (App-V)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_App-V). You may have a Click & Run Version of Office installaed which internally uses App-V and this is why you see the drive.

You can [hide it very easily by importing this .reg file](http://www.networknet.nl/apps/wp/archives/1299) to the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoDrives"=dword:00010000
"NoViewOnDrive"=dword:00010000
```

Comment: This is it. "Problem" solved! Why didn't they hide it in first place... People like me may think they've got a vírus or something..

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at which disk the drive is coming from, by opening the "Properties" dialog. Also, check device manager for disks. Don't forget to try to give yourself full permissions. You can, for example, run a command prompt as system (http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/22/getting-a-cmd-prompt-as-system-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008.aspx) and try then. You can also always attach a debugger and look at how the system is trying to execute your requests.

If I had to guess I'd say that this is caused by a driver. Did you install software recently?